# i3wm: invoking program via i3 in one workspace, invoking program via terminal in another

Tags: i3

I have currently configured my i3 to open Firefox in a specific workspace any time it boots up, but is there a way to have Firefox open in say workspace 2 if it is opened via i3 (mod+d) but open in my active workspace if it is invoked via anything but i3 e.g: googler or direct from my terminal

Answer (score 1):

In your `i3/.config` file, you can use the assign class functionality described in the [i3 User Documentation](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#assign_workspace)

Run `xprop` from your terminal, and then click on the window (e.g., Firefox) to see what class it belongs to. Look for `WM_CLASS(STRING)`.

Then, it's as simple as putting the following line in your .config file:

```
assign [class="Firefox"] 2
```

Don't forget to restart your instance using (default) `$Mod + Shift + r`